# Angular proxy.conf.js pass environment variables from CI/CD

Tags: angular, continuous-integration, environment-variables, continuous-deployment

Is there a way to pass the server URL using environment variables of CI/CD?

I am trying to make testing CI/CD for my project. The problem is that for angular cypress test I need access to server. depending on who runs the pipelines they would have access to different servers, so I want them to be able to change proxy.conf.json using environment variables on bitbucket.

my current proxy.conf.json is:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": "/api"
    },
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

I want to achieve:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": $MY_SERVER_ENV_VARIABLE,
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": "/api"
    },
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

So I want to pass $MY_SERVER_ENV_VARIABLE from Bitbucket CI/CD. **Is it possible?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On of the options is to make `js` conf file instead of `json` file. [Here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md#multiple-entries) is the docs.

Now you are can use NodeJS `process` global variable. You can get env variables through it.

So, the code of `proxy.conf.js` will be:

```
const DEFAULT_TARGET = "localhost:3000";
const PROXY_CONFIG = {
  "/api": {
    "target": process.env.YOUR_ENV_VARIABLE || DEFAULT_TARGET,
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": "/api"
    },
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
};

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

Don't forget to change a path to the config file in `angular.json` file.